# Negotiating new car prices in Spain

Tags: spain, car, culture

I used to sell cars in the US, where it is normal for car buyers to negotiate final sale price of the vehicle, even on a new car.

I'm looking to purchase a new vehicle in Spain. Is it normal/acceptable to negotiate the price of a new vehicle in Spain? If so, how much movement on the price can be expected?

Answer (score 2):

You can try, but don't expect a big discount.

What I would advice is that you shop around. Visit different dealerships, ask for quotes and see what they have to offer.

Not sure about other places, but in Spain there is the concept of a Km0 car. Cars that the dealership might have bought themselves to reach a certain quota and now are eager to sell at a discount. Sometimes the cars have been used for demoing, or been in the exhibition.

Usually cars are sold on demand, and the dealership only orders the from the manufacturer when the have an order for them.

Comment: This also happens in the UK, what they call "pre-registered".  The dealer is usually given some kind of offer from the manufacturer "take 3 of these less popular models and I've give you x discount on the ones you want", and as the dealer is officially the first owner, the car can be sold on (untouched) without the tax (so about 20% cheaper than new) without the dealer losing on the cost (VAT is charged on new cars and as the dealer is VAT registered they won't need to pay).